# What is the best way to slice a multiindex dataframe using a list of partial index tuples?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, partial, multi-index

I want to slice a data frame using a partially matching index, or list of tuples.

```
_ix = [('foo','a', 1), ('foo','a', 2), ('foo','b', 1), 
       ('foo','b', 2), ('foo','c', 1), ('foo','c', 2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((6, 1)), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(_ix))
print(df)

           0
foo a 1  1.0
      2  1.0
    b 1  1.0
      2  1.0
    c 1  1.0
      2  1.0
```

Given a query index like:

```
q_ix = [('foo', 'a'), ('foo', 'c')]
```

I want to obtain

```
           0
foo a 1  1.0
      2  1.0
    c 1  1.0
      2  1.0
```

I *can* get this by using `pd.concat` and a list comprehension...

```
df_sliced = pd.concat([df.loc[(*x, slice(None)), :] for x in q_ix])
```

...but this is super clunky when my query index is large.  Is there no better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.IndexSlice` from `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.IndexSlice


df.loc[idx[:, ['a', 'c']], :] # Can use 'foo' instead of : on the first lvl
```

outputs

```
           0
foo a 1  1.0
      2  1.0
    c 1  1.0
      2  1.0
```

It reads take everything along the first level (`:`) then on the second level grab `["a", "c"]`. Which we enclose in `idx` to mark that it is a slice. Finally, the last `:` tells that we want all the columns.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
df.reset_index(level=2).loc[q_ix].set_index('level_2',append=True)
                 0
      level_2     
foo a 1        1.0
      2        1.0
    c 1        1.0
      2        1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `index.droplevel` and `isin`, and `.loc` on the mask as follows

```
n = df.index.droplevel(2).isin(q_ix)

Out[75]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True])

df.loc[n]

Out[76]:
           0
foo a 1  1.0
      2  1.0
    c 1  1.0
      2  1.0
```